# Loop through split value cells and replace

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, split, str-replace

I have created a macro in Excel. In column A values are separated by a semicolon.

There is a loop through split values in column A replacing split values in column B.

Looping through split values doesn't work.

```
Sub ReplaceAttachments3()
Dim cl As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim txt As String
For Each cl In Range("$B$1:$B" & Range("$B65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    txt = Cells(cl.Row, 1)
    cell = split(txt, ";")
    For i = 0 To UBound(cell)
        Cells(cl.Row, 2).replace What:=txt,   Replacement:="",LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Application.Goto Reference:="ReplaceAttachments"
    Next i
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Text To Columns`? VBA is not required. And if you still want VBA then record a macro for  `Text To Columns`

Comment: I would like to replace split values in the B column. For example in column A: "a;b;c;" column B: "text a text2 b text2   c" , and in column B I would like replace values like a,b,c on empty values.

Comment: so you want to remove the split values from col B?

Comment: yes, I want remove te split values from column B and this split value are in column A separated by semicolon

Comment: Ok. I have posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it. Hope this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? Note you do not need to select the complete column. Simply find the last row and work with that range only :)

I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. But if you do then simply post back.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim MyAr

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in Col A
        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)

        '~~> Loop trhough your range
        For Each aCell In rng
            '~~> Skip the row if value in cell A is blank
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Check if the cell has ";"
                '~~> If it has ";" then split and replace else
                '~~> Replace without splitting
                If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ";") Then
                    MyAr = Split(aCell.Value, ";")

                    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                        aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Replace(aCell.Offset(, 1).Value, Trim(MyAr(i)), "")
                    Next i
                Else
                    aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Replace(aCell.Offset(, 1).Value, Trim(aCell.Value), "")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]